# Delete a user from sites

Tags: support, deleted-accounts

How do I remove my userid from 
http://answers.onstartups.com/ 
http://area51.stackexchange.com/ 
https://gaming.stackexchange.com/ 
https://stackapps.com/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Contact the team@stackoverflow.com or flag one of your posts on the relevant site for moderator attention.

They will ask you to update your profile with some information to verify that it is really you asking.

Once you've done that they'll delete the account.

Comment: Thanks. +1 I really enjoy stackoverflow but have not used the other sites.